# Google beacon tools not able to configure Virtual Ibeacon

Tags: ios, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

[image: unable to configure]

I want to make a IOS device act as a virtual Ibeacon and configure it to google proximaty API.

When I try to configure using google beacon tools. I get "eddystone configuration not supported by the beacon"

Can any one help me to understand on what basis Google says Ibeacon is supported for nearby notifications

Comment: Why would you think that you could use a Google app to make an iOS device act as an Eddystone beacon?  Eddystone is Google's standard.  If you want an iOS device to act as a beacon you need to either write some iOS code or download an app from the store

Comment: Google says they support iBeacon in there platform. I don’t want to convert iPhone to Eddystone beacon.    Instead I want to configure virtual iBeacon with google beacon platform.

Comment: Sounds to me like this is not a programming question.  Or if it is, can you share your code?

Comment: Your screenshot shows an app running on Android - How is this going to make an iOS device do anything?  You need to show the code you are running on the iOS device.  An iOS device won't act as an iBeacon without you running some code to make it do so.  You can get apps from the App Store to do this

Comment: @Paulw11 there is no code to run here . I created a virtual ibeacon from some third party apps on my iphone . Then tried to configure using beacon tools app on my android phone (above screen shot) . beacon tools ios  app is not available in my region

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can use Google's Beacon Tools app to register a virtual iPhone iBeacon transmitter with Google's servers.**  The problem is that you are misunderstanding the meaning of that error message.

To clarify:  The question shows a screenshot of an Android app that has scanned for an iBeacon transmission coming from an iOS device.

**Provisioning** shows "Eddystone configuration service not supported by this beacon" because that section is used for configuring the beacon over bluetooth using the Eddystone configuration GATT service standard.  Because your iPhone doesn't support that GATT service (lots of beacons don't -- not just virtual beacons), you get that error message.

Don't worry, that section is optional.

**Just skip it and go down to the next section labelled Registration.**